# How to use common ViewController to get previous viewcontroller's value?

Tags: ios, swift

In my App,

I have a CommonViewController that provide other ViewController to use.

If MyViewController pushed to CommonViewController

In my CommonViewController, How should I get MyViewController value?

I know I can pass data From MyVC to CommonVC

But this situation CommonVC is Common

This way could cause CommonVC has a lot of variable

Here's MyViewController

```
class MyViewController:UIViewController {
var a = String()
var b = String()
var c = String()

//In this VC ,I use textField to save user typed result 
  a = "123" b = "456" c = "789"
//And push to CommonVC

}
```

Here's CommonViewController

```
class CommonViewController:UIViewcontroller {

@IBAction func enterBtnPressAction(_ sender: Any){
  //I need to use MyVC's value to do something 
 }

}
```

My brain get sucked with CommonVC concept

Every VC has chance to use

The Button func enterBtnPressAction

need to process a variety of situation

if these two VC only allow me to use

I can easily pass value from A to B

but CommonVC need to be used from others

It will look like CommonVC has MyVC's a、b、c variable

And someday CommonVC has other VC's variables

Is there better way to fix this condition ?

I'm really new, now good at questioning if need more info just ask for me, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyViewController:UIViewController {
    var a = String()
    var b = String()
    var c = String()

    //In this VC ,I use textField to save user typed result

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        a = "123"
        b = "456"
        c = "789"
    }
    //And push to CommonVC
    @IBAction func pushToCommonVC(_ sender: Any){
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        // “common-VC” you need to set this identifier from storyboard select your viewController and set from inpector right side menu
        let commonVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "common-VC") as! commonVC
        commonVC.a = a
        commonVC.b = b
        commonVC.c = c
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(commonVC, animated: true)
    }

}
class CommonViewController:UIViewcontroller {
    var a = String()
    var b = String()
    var c = String()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //values will print here
        print("\(a)")
        print("\(b)")
        print("\(c)")
    }
    @IBAction func enterBtnPressAction(_ sender: Any){
        //I need to use MyVC's value to do something
        //here you can use your a,b,c values
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use concept of inheritance like CommonVC should be super superclass of all vc required to access Common VC

Example

```
class CommonViewController:UIViewcontroller {

@IBAction func enterBtnPressAction(_ sender: Any){
  //I need to use MyVC's value to do something 
 }

}
```

Class MyViewController uses common vc enterBtnPress action by override

```
class MyViewController:CommonViewController {
var a = String()
var b = String()
var c = String()

//In this VC ,I use textField to save user typed result 
  a = "123" b = "456" c = "789"
//And push to CommonVC
override func enterBtnPressAction(_ sender: Any){
      //You can use MyVC's value to do something 
     }

}
```

Class AnotherVC uses common vc enterBtnPress action by override

```
class AnotherController:CommonViewController {
    var p = String()
    var q = String()
    var r = String()

    //In this VC ,I use textField to save user typed result 
      p = "123" q = "456" r = "789"
    //And push to CommonVC
    override func enterBtnPressAction(_ sender: Any){
          //You can use AnotherVC value to do something 
         }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the values in commonView controller from Main VC you should pass values from mainVC to Common VC by using the story board identifier.

You should write this piece of code in button click of MyViewController:

```
let myVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "identifier of commonviewcontroller declared in main storyboard") as! CommonViewController
                myVC.avalue = a
                myVC.bvalue = b
                myVC.cvalue = c
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)
```

Next in CommonViewController you should declare the variables to store the passed values from My View COntroller :

```
    class CommonViewController: UIViewController{

        var avalue:String = ""
        var bvalue:String = ""
        var cvalue:String = ""
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


        }
      @IBAction func enterBtnPressAction(_ sender: Any){

      // Now you can use the values here.

   }
}
```